# Given a sequence converges to 2, we construct a new series, does it converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Suppose we know that $a_n \rightarrow 2$, which is a sequence with positive terms, determine whether the following series converges:
>
> $$ \sum \frac{a_n}{n + a_n^2} $$

I would like to apply a variation of the ratio test:
$$ \lim_ {n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1+ a_{n+1}^2}}{\frac{a_n}{n + a_n^2} }= \lim_ {n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \left(\frac{n+ a_n^2}{n+1+ a_n^2}\right)=\lim_ {n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \left(\frac{1+\frac{a_n^2}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{a_{n+1}^2}{n}}\right)= \frac{2}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{1}.$$
We know that $a_n$ converges and it bounded, so we know that $\frac{a_n^2}{n} \rightarrow 0$
But now the ratio test is inconclusive, can someone drop a hint for an alternative approach perhaps?

Comment: Limit comparison test against $2/n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't converge because the terms of the sequence do not shrink fast enough. Since we know that $a_n\rightarrow 2$, there is some $N$ such that $a_n\in(3/2,5/2)$ for all $n>N$. Then
$$
\frac{a_n}{n+a_n^2}>\frac{3/2}{n+25/4}>\frac{1}{n}
$$
for all $n>\max(13,N)$. By the comparison test on the tail of your sequence starting from the $\max (13,N)$ we see that your series diverges.

Comment: I like this argument

Comment: This is basically what we discussed in class, this is very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo You are welcome! I think you will find this kind of reasoning will give you a lot of mileage in analysis. Anytime you are given a limit, that also gives you a way of approximating values, and with enough wiggle room (as my professor used to say) you can usually find the proof you want.

Comment: Yes, the trick is always to find a nice approximation, I feel I'm getting more adept at it, but not quite sure when to use this method and when not. I will keep practising. I'm really enjoying analysis so far.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple with *equivalence*:

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=2$, then $\; a_n\sim_\infty 2$. It is easy to check $\;n+ a_n^2\sim_\infty n$, therefore
$$ \frac{a_n}{n+a_n^2}\sim_\infty\frac 2n,$$
which diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try the sequence $a_n=2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Cleary $\frac{2}{n+2}$ diverges, because the harmonic series does. I think the question wants an answer for general $a_n$ but this answer inspires the comparison given by other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotically this new series $\approx\frac{2}{n+4}$, so diverges.

Answer (score 1):

By [**limit comparison test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), since eventually $a_n$ is positive

$$\frac{\frac{a_n}{n + a_n^2}}{\frac1n}=\frac{a_n\cdot n}{n + a_n^2}=\frac{a_n}{1 + \frac{a_n^2}n}\to 2$$

therefore the given series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

When $a_n\to 2$ there exists $N$ such that $$\forall n>N\qquad,\qquad  1<a_n<3$$therefore $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n\over n+a_n^2}=K+\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} {1\over {n\over a_n}+a_n}\ge K+\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}{1\over {n+3}}=\infty$$therefore the series diverges.